# Why unboxing doesn't work : Unresolved compilation error: Cannot cast from double to Long?

Tags: java, unboxing

As per my understanding, Java automatically takes care of Autoboxing and Unboxing i.e., conversion of Primitives to Object Wrappers and vice a versa. However, unboxing doesn't seem to be working in below code.

```
public class TestMath {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long resultLong = (Long) Math.pow(10, 10);
        System.out.println(resultLong);
    }
}
```

The above code gives me compilation error until I manually do unboxing by replacing **(Long)** with **(long)**. I would like to understand the reason behind this.

The compilation error is as shown below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Cannot cast from double to Long

Comment: And what exactly is the compilation error, and on which line? Please make it as easy as possible for us to help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet - I've posted the compilation error. It's at line **Long resultLong = (Long) Math.pow(10, 10);**

Comment: Right - thank you. Please bear this in mind for future questions. Note that your code doesn't try to do any unboxing, btw.

Comment: `Autoboxing` means convert from primitive type long to `java.lang.Long` class. `Unboxing` means convert from `Long` to long. You cannot convert implicitly from double to long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Math.pow(10, 10)` returns a `double`, which can be auto-boxed into a `Double`, not into a `Long`.

If you explicitly cast the result to `long`, the compiler can auto-box the `long` to `Long`.

As to why `(Long) Math.pow(10, 10)` doesn't work - there is no conversion from `double` to `Long` defined in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7). The only supported boxing conversions are from a primitive to its corresponding reference type:

> **5.1.7. Boxing Conversion**
>
> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstood/confused with *casting* and *boxing/unboxing*. They both are different concepts.

```
 Math.pow(10, 10)
```

That returns a double and boxing/unboxing happens between respective primitives and wrappers (`int <=> Integer` , `long <=> Long`). Not with other types (`double <!=!> Long`).

Since you are trying to assign a double to long value, the compiler giving you the error. However assigning to Double works.

```
Double resultLong =   Math.pow(10, 10);
```

In the above line, pow method actually returns the type `double` and will be converted to Double as they both are a pair of primitive and wrapper.

Comment: "Since you are trying to assign a double to long value, the compiler giving you the error. However casting works as you are allowed cast types." No, the compiler error clearly says it's the *cast* that is the problem.

Comment: @AndyTurner My bad. Corrected. Thankyou.